# Implicit type casting in Java

Tags: java, casting

I know type casting is done automatically in Java for lower precision primitive type to higher precision. For example in this code :

```
int i = 20;
int j = 40;
float k = i + j; //explicit casting not required
```

My question is, what actually happens internally? In the third statement, do the values of `i` and `j` individually get casted to `float` and then added together?

Or the addition is done first in `int` type and then the result of addition is casted into `float`?

Comment: They're added as its and then casted to floats.

Comment: They are added and after that, they are casted.

Comment: Try it with `double d = i / j`, and you'll see. This is a very frequent bug.

Comment: This is explained in detail in the Java documentation. Where did you look for your answer? Did you read the Java Language Specification (JLS) regarding this topic? Check out the sections on numeric widening conversion especially with binary operators.

Comment: @LewBloch I did take a look at that but I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for, it seemed to me like you need to have a really technical vocabulary to find the right thing and section for the info you are looking for,  I also tried searching articles but all I could find was explanation of what type casting is and difference between implicit and explicit.

Comment: @Master Yushi You want http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6. Read and study the JLS. "It's too difficult" is a temporary friction on learning unless you use it as an excuse not to learn. You will be useless as a Java programmer until you're in the habit of knowing the JLS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are added as ints (like they would if you executed `i+j` without an assignment), and then casted to float because of the assignment.

However if you executed `float k = (float) i + j` then `j` would be casted to a float because the left hand side of the addition is a float ... Same for `float k = 1.0f*i + j`

Makes sense?

Answer (score 5):

Let's take a look!

```
$ cat > temp.java
class temp {
    public void f() {
        int i = 20;
        int j = 40;
        float k = i + j; //explicit casting not required
    }
}

$ javac temp.java
$ javap -c temp
Compiled from "temp.java"
class temp {
  temp();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public void f();
    Code:
       0: bipush        20
       2: istore_1
       3: bipush        40
       5: istore_2
       6: iload_1
       7: iload_2
       8: iadd
       9: i2f
      10: fstore_3
      11: return
}
```

As you can see, first they are added as integers (instruction 8), then casted to a float (instruction 9).

Comment: Is that the terminal? Looks like a great tool to see what happens under the hood. I never dug into compiling and executing code through cmd but this seems helpful. I couldn't fully understand it but I figured out what you were trying to explain. `iadd` (int addition?) happens first and then `i2f` (int to float type cast?). Did I get it?

Comment: Yes, it is. [Javap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javap.html) is the built-in disassembler for java, which shows the bytecode contained in a .class file.

If that interests you, you might want to look around for some guide of the java bytecode. For instance, the documentation of the widely-used [ASM library](http://asm.ow2.org/) has some nice documentation which explains both the library and how the bytecode works.

Answer (score 3):

Implicit casting is *not* applied to parts of the expression, but to the result of the computation as a whole.

You can demonstrate this with a simple example:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
float c = a / b;
```

The above assigns zero to `c`, not `0.5f`, which would be the result if casting to `float` were applied to `a` and/or to `b`.

Comment: Thanks for the example, that clears it up completely!